# Google Pagespeed insights on local host not working

Tags: google-api, localhost, pagespeed-insights, localserver, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am trying to run webpage insights on a website by first downloading it locally and then using local server to test it. But, I am getting error like
Performance Score = {'error': {'code': 500, 'message': 'Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)', 'errors': [{'message': 'Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Details: net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED)', 'domain': 'lighthouse', 'reason': 'lighthouseError'}]}}
4505.094128370285
and my code looks like this:

```
# Download the website files
subprocess.run(["wget", "-r", "-p", "-np", url])

# Start the local server
url_path = url.split("//")[1]
server_process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-m", "http.server"], cwd=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), url_path))
# Wait for the server to start up
requests.get("http://localhost:8000/")

# Run PageSpeed Insights analysis
pagespeed_url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=http://localhost:8000/&key={API_KEY}"
response = requests.get(pagespeed_url)
data = response.json()
performance_score = data
print(f"{url}: Performance Score = {performance_score}")
# Stop the local server
server_process.kill()
```

I want to receive my pagespeed insight results launched via local host such that external factors like number of users and network congestion doesn't affect my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PageSpeed Insights is a web service. It need to be able to contact the service it is testing. Localhost is a private address to you and will not be on the internet for others and web services to contact.

You want to use Lighthouse (which PSI runs), either from Chrome Dev Tools or the command line.